# JDBC returns an empty ResultSet (rs.isBeforeFirst() == true) although the table isn't empty

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to complete a DB access method for my Web Service. The service and the DB access methods work fine for all other tables in the DB, but this one particular method does not. When I query the DB, the `ResultSet` always returns empty (meaning `isBeforeFirst() == true`).

After many tries I cut my query to a simple `SELECT * FROM VIDEOS` to see if the problem is some difference between the data I entered and the data I use in my query, but even this simple query to select all items in the table didn't return any result.

This is the method I use to pull info from the DB:

```
public static Object[] getVideo(String phonenum, String timeStamp)
{
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    Object[] result = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:lineappDB.db");
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM VIDEOS");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        // If no data was found
        if (rs.isBeforeFirst())
        {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            c.close();
            return null;
        } else
        {
            result = new Object[6];
            while (rs.next())
            {
                result[0] = rs.getInt(1);
                result[1] = rs.getString(2);
                result[2] = rs.getString(3);
                result[3] = rs.getString(4);
                result[4] = rs.getString(5);
                result[5] = rs.getInt(6);
            }
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!c.isClosed())
            {
                c.commit();
                c.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println(ex.getClass().getName() + ": " + ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("Succesfully pulled from DB - %s %s", result[1], result[2]));
    return result;
}
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

CLARIFICATION EDIT: 
The method is part of a web service that pulls a path of a certain video from the DB, to be sent to a client. The videos are uploaded by clients and are then stored in the filesystem, and their paths are stored in the DB itself.

Once I see the DB works, I will replace `SELECT * FROM VIDEOS` with `SELECT * FROM VIDEOS WHERE PHONENUM = '%s' AND DATETIME = '%s'", phonenum, timeStamp` so that the query pulls the exact item I need.

Comment: I would put all `.close()` commands into an `finally` block

Comment: @David Thank you for the advice, I will do so.

Comment: @David when I put my `.close()` commands in a `finally` block, eclipse yells that I didn't handle exceptions. And so I will need to use a double `try catch` block again. Could you show a correct example?

Comment: @1CodeRed actually, in this day and age, why not use the [try-with-resource idiom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`isBeforeFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isBeforeFirst()) returns `true` if the next call to `next()` will put the cursor on the first row of the `ResultSet`. In other words, any successful query that has data, once executed, will produce a `ResultSet` with `isBeforeFirst()` returning `true`.

Just remove that block from your code, and have the `rs.next()` loop deal with potentially empty `ResultSet`s:

```
try
{
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:lineappDB.db");
    c.setAutoCommit(false);
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
    stmt = c.createStatement();
    String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM VIDEOS");

    result = new Object[6];
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next())
    {
        result[0] = rs.getInt(1);
        result[1] = rs.getString(2);
        result[2] = rs.getString(3);
        result[3] = rs.getString(4);
        result[4] = rs.getString(5);
        result[5] = rs.getInt(6);
    }
} 
/* catch and finally snipped for clarity of the answer */
```

Comment: Very simple solution, thank you very much. I am surprised I didn't get this problem with other tables. What a dumb mistake :)

Comment: (cc: @1CodeRed ) +1 for the explanation of what `.isBeforeFirst()` really means. In fact, the test for an empty ResultSet is when `.isBeforeFirst()` returns `false`, not `true` (as the OP thought).

Comment: Hey Mureinik, Yuval suppose to use if (!rs.isBeforeFirst()) to check whether the result set it empty or not. If it is not empty then he can proceed further and consume the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Use if (!rs.isBeforeFirst()) instead of if (rs.isBeforeFirst()). your problem would be solved.