# Results are not available after executing query (JDBC)

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a function which has to block the user and in it I'm checking if there are any results, however, somehow it always breaks on the while loop returning `Results are not available` even though I set to return from the function if there are no results available. Am I doing something wrong with handling `ResultSet`? This method of checking for no results worked well in all other functions, but makes problem here.

```
public static boolean block(int id, int blocktime) throws Exception, SQLException {
    DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
    db.establishConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = ?");
    db.setIntParameter(1, id);
    db.executeQuery();

    if (!db.results().isBeforeFirst()) {
        Notify.accountIdInvalid();
        db.close();
        return false;
    }

    while (db.results().next()) {
        int blocked = db.results().getInt("blocked");
        if (blocked == 1) { db.close(); Notify.accountAlreadyBlocked(); return false; }
        else {
            db.close();
            DatabaseConnection db2 = new DatabaseConnection();
            db2.establishConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE accounts SET blocked = 1, blocktime = ? WHERE id = ?");
            db2.setIntParameter(1, blocktime);
            db2.setIntParameter(2, id);
            db2.executeUpdate();
            db2.close();
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here are some of my functions in `DatabaseConnection` for dealing with statements and results. Process is always the same, I establish connection, prepare statement and execute query (or update) which returns me results to work with.

```
/**
 * Executes the query.
 * 
 * @return DatabaseConnection
 * @throws Exception if statement doesn't exists.
 */
public DatabaseConnection executeQuery() throws Exception {
    if (this.stmt == null) {
        throw new Exception("Statement for query executing doesn't exist.");
    }

    this.rs = this.stmt.executeQuery();
    return this;
}

/**
 * Executes the update.
 * 
 * @throws Exception 
 */
public void executeUpdate() throws Exception {
    if (this.stmt == null) {
        throw new Exception("Statement for query updating doesn't exist.");
    }

    this.stmt.executeUpdate();
}

/**
 * Returns the results from executed query.
 * 
 * @return ResultSet
 * @throws Exception if results aren't available.
 */
public ResultSet results() throws Exception {
    if (this.rs == null) {
        throw new Exception("Results are not available.");
    }

    return this.rs;
}
```

I don't think it's relevant, but anyway; I'm working with MySQL database.

Comment: Where exactly are the error occurring? Is it on the IF or in the while statement?

Comment: On the while statement.

Comment: So, your problem is the `isBeforeFirst` method. Take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/26324689/460557

Comment: @JorgeCampos So, you suggest I should delete this `if` part if I understood correctly?

Comment: Not exactly, if you understand that answer, you will see that a call to [`isBeforeFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isBeforeFirst()) will check the RecordSet pointer position which will move it making your while returns that error. I would remove the while and just check the next with an IF

Comment: @JorgeCampos Oh, I understand now, thanks! It's weird how it worked well with same approach in other methods (`Account.exists()`, `Account.hasMoney()` etc). I'll use it now.

Comment: If it work the same way in other methods it may worth to check the queries on it. It most probably wrong resulting in more than one row.  Cheers

Comment: @JorgeCampos Actually all methods in class `Account` have same starting query (`SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = ?`), but never mind, what matters is that it works. Cheers!